# Three.js make object.rotation.x Smooth

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have .obj of logo that I load to a canvas using three.js. The logo is a part of a website loading section that I'm working. There is a 'Click to Enter' button on that section. All I want to do is when someone click on the enter button, logo to rotate 180 degrees vertically.

I'm using

```
var deg = Math.PI / 180 * 180;
object.rotation.x -= deg;
```

The logo rotation works, But it's not smooth. I want it be smooth(like transiton).

I really appreciate any help on this matter. 
Also here is the [link](http://infinitedesigns.epizy.com/360-web/) to the test page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use an animation library like [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/) in order to animate such transitions. This will also allow you to choose between different easing functions which will make your animation even more smooth.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I used tween.js and now animation works.